# Looking to improve Solr filter query on Multi-Valued field which is taking more than 2 seconds

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a string multivalued field, each document may have up to 6000 values for this field, the values are just ids, ie., single word alpha-numeric identifier.

While querying, I am adding a filter query(fq) to filter documents which are having a certain identifier in the multivalued field. I am facing a performance issue that the query takes ~2 to 4 seconds but when I am using filter query on the single-valued field, I am getting the result within ~1 seconds. Is there any way to improve the query performance?

**Schema.xml Entries**

I am using the dynamic field

**Query**

fq=(mvfield1_string_mv:aa123+OR+mvfield2_string_mv:bb456)

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I have tried to increase the filter query cache, the hit ratio is 0.95 but it's still the taking around 4 secs. Also, the memory utilization is minimal so I don't see the need to increase the memory allocation

[image: Filter and Query Cache stats]

Comment: The total number of terms is usually more relevant than the field being multivalued. If the filters are often identical, a filter cache will speed up things greatly - otherwise the initial query will usually take the most time, with any subsequent queries being sped up because of OS disk caches You might also have to give Solr more memory to work with, so that it can keep more of the index in memory instead of it having to hit the disk each time.

Comment: @MatsLindh, Thanks for your reply, Increasing filter cache size didn't help, please find the image attached in the question and also, the memory utilization is minimal